# Resource-specific Devise Layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have two devise models, Admins and Users, and I have resource-specific views for them. `config.scoped_views = true`
The problem is that I don't know how to specify layouts for these views - the Devise Wiki describes a way to specify controller-specific layouts [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-custom-layouts).
Is there a way to use application layout for Admins and a custom layout for Users Devise pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example on the page you linked does almost exactly that. With a little modification it will use the application layout for Admins and some custom layout for Users.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller? && resource_name == :user
      "custom_user_layout"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```